# Error while injecting Serilog "Prism.DryIoc DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection6.0.0 "

Tags: c#, prism, dryioc

I have this code.

```
protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddLogging(configure =>
            {
                configure.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
            });

            return new DryIocContainerExtension(new Container(CreateContainerRules())
                .WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(serviceCollection));
        }
```

When I use `DryIoc. Microsoft. DependencyInjection 5.1.0` upgrade to `DryIoc.Microsoft. DependencyInjection6.0.0`,

```
return new DryIocContainerExtension(new Container(CreateContainerRules())
            .WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(serviceCollection));
```

I have this error

```
 "Method not found: 'DryIoc.Rules DryIoc.Rules.WithoutFastExpressionCompiler()"
```

What should I do? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WithoutFastExpressionCompiler` is no longer an option in DryIoc v5 and DryIoc.MD.DI v6 per dependency. Prism.DryIoc should adapt. Please open an issue in the Prism repo.

Comment: I've found this issue on Github,Just wait for prism update